# Undefined Object but I got something in console log

Tags: html, json, angular, angular2-services

I am trying to access product.img_url but an error tells me it is undefined. When I tried to use console log, it clearly shows that my product object has a value. Can anyone help me in this?

product.component.ts

```
export class ProductComponent implements OnInit{
    product: Products;

    constructor(private _router: Router, private _productsService: ProductsService){}

    ngOnInit(){
        var str = this._router.url;
        var param = str.split("/");
        this._productsService.getProductById(param[2], param[3])
            .subscribe((product) => {this.product = product; console.log(product);}),
            (err) => console.log(err);
    }

}
```

HTML div

```
            <div class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane active" id="product-page1" [hidden]="product">
                    <img src="{{product.img_url}}" alt="..."/>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Error stack trace

[image]

console.log output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I already found out the problem here.

The object becomes an array after I get it therefore I need to put [0] when accessing the index of the array in HTML. The code looks like this.

```
<img src="{{product[0].img_url}}" alt="..."/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If product can be undefined at the point of binding, which it can in this case there are two options.

You could use ngIf to only render the img element when a product exists.

```
 <img *ngIf="product" src="{{product.img_url}}" alt="..."/>
```

Or use the safe naivgation operator '?'

```
<img src="{{product?.img_url}}" alt="..."/>
```

Comment: i moved the *ngIf to the div tag ang put {{product.img_url}} inside. no display but the div is there.

EDIT: I tried to remove img_url just {{product}} and it gave me  [object Object] inside the div.

Comment: I assumed product was an individual product but it looks like product should be products? If that is the case you would want an ngFor to iterate the products.